# Select parent selector in SASS/SCSS

Tags: html, css, sass, bem

I have a small missunderstanding in SCSS syntax. Creating small component using BEM methodology and got a problem in SCSS.
HTML:

```
<div class="message message--success">
        <div class="message__title">
          BEM Example
        </div>
        <div class="message__content">
          <p>BEM Example text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

SCSS:

```
.message {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;

  &__title {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #000;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }

  &__content {
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #000;
  }

  &--success {
    border-color: #3f9442;

    &__title {
      color: #3f9442;
    }

    &__content {
      color: #3f9442;
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, I have **.message--success** class and inside &--success the direct styles(border-color) works, but stylyng for title and content not. How to select **.message* as parent for **&__title** and **&__content** inside **&--success**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either you write both the selectors with the full classname (without using `&`) or you could save a reference to the `.message` class and use it in the nested selector

```
.message {

  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;

  $this: &; /* reference to the .message class */

  &__title {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #000;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }

  &__content {
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #000;
  }

  &--success {
    border-color: #3f9442;

    /* use the reference stored */

    #{$this}__title {
      color: #3f9442;
    }

    #{$this}__content {
      color: #3f9442;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Storing the `&` in a variable is also a possibility.

Comment: Both answers are ok, but I prefer with reference, it looks cleaner

Comment: When trying this method, vscode editor showing error and warnings in console. but this compiling and working perfectly. why vscode code showing this error and how to fix it? sample code #{$this}__megamenu{color:red}

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
.message {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;

  &__title {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #000;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }

  &__content {
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #000;
  }

  &--success {
    border-color: #3f9442;
    .message{
      &__title {
        color: #3f9442;
      }

      &__content {
        color: #3f9442;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/21b3cksm/4/